# Sticky footer not sticking to the bottom when viewed in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement sticky footer for a page which has the bootstrap simple sidebar.

In desktop view the footer seems to stick to bottom of the page regardless if the sidebar is collapsed or not. But when viewed on mobile device the footer does not stick to bottom of the page. You can see that happening in the jsfiddle example. If you shrink the size of the result page and toggle the sidebar, footer appears in middle of the page.

Could someone point out why this is happening?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">


        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>

                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
<div id="push"></div>
</div>

<!-- /#wrapper -->
<div id="footer">

  <div class="container">
    <p class="muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
.top-nav {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1029;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#search-page.col-xs-2 {
    width: 20%;
}


#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width:70%;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}


  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push,
      #footer {
        height: 60px;
      }
      #footer {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        #footer {
          margin-left: -20px;
          margin-right: -20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      }

.footer {
background-color: #EDEDED;
height: 30em;
z-index: 1050;
}
```

jQuery version: 1.10.1

http://jsfiddle.net/tgbej11a/

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, the footer sticks to the bottom even if I reduce the result's window to its minimum width.

Comment: It's because when you toggle it, you have your sidebar as fixed (which is fine) but your content's container is given the position absolute. Therefore, the only thing that's relative is the div 'push' so the footer would go right underneath that. For example, instead of applying a position of absolute to the content, give it a position of relative and your footer will be at the bottom. Of course, you're going to come across new problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the CSS to solve the problem in your latest fiddle too

```
.top-nav {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1029;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#search-page.col-xs-2 {
    width: 20%;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
* Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
* For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
*/
/* Toggle Styles */
#wrapper, #footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled, #wrapper.toggled + #footer {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 15px;
}
    /* Sidebar Styles */
.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper, #wrapper + #footer {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled, #wrapper.toggled + #footer {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#push {
    height: 60px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#footer .container {
    margin-left: 0;
}
    /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
        margin-right: -20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
}

.footer {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. The above approach worked. I have one more question, right now the side bar when opened will cover the footer, in both mobile version and desktop. Is there a way around it. Here is latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/htLcsb6h/